# How to sort the activation output according to their probabilities in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can I choose 100 top labels  out of 5528 labels according to their probabilities in descending order?

I am trying to solve a multilabel problem in keras using tensorflow backend. I have done onehot encoding to my labels (5528 in total) using `class_mode="categorical"` in keras `imagedatagenerator`. Train images have variable number of images and test images can have up to maximum 100 images.

For my multi label classification problem, i wrote following layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(50,50,3)))
...
...
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5528, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="binary_crossentropy",
metrics=accuracy"])
```

Out of these 5528 labels, I want to select labels with  top 100 probabilities.

For this, I wrote this function:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Lambda

def top_k(input, k):
  return tf.nn.top_k(input, k=k, sorted=True).indices
```

And added a layer

```
model.add(Lambda(top_k, input_shape=(5528,), arguments={'k':100}))`
```

before compiling.

When I used `.values` , it gave me no results(labels) whereas when i used `.indices`, it gave me following error:

```
TypeError: Expected int32, got 1e-07 of type 'float' instead.
```

I am quite confused, what exactly should I use, `.indices` or `.values`?

Also, I want to ask if the way in which I write input shape inside Lambda is correct or not?